# Regex to match character when the character to the left is not \

Tags: regex

I have a string that I would like to return: `hello\'world` from the following string: `'hello\'world'`

My regex pattern that currently does not work is the following: `'[^']+'`

This pattern gets all text that is within two single quotes. However, in my example, I would like it to ignore the single quote that has the `\` character before it. Currently, my pattern above would return `hello\` and another match as `world`

How can I achieve this desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following literally matches a quote (`'`) then groups anything that follows (`(.*)`) that is followed by a quote (`'`) not preceded by a slash (negative lookbehind: `(?<!\\)`)

```
'(.+)(?<!\\)'
```

Comment: Instead of "anything" can I modify (.*) to exclude `'`?

Comment: You don't want to.  It will only match a quote that does not follow a slash.  If the quote doesn't follow a slash, you have found the end of your string.

Comment: Yeah--this is straying away from my initial question that you have provided a valid answer for. I'll accept this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use an alternation with look arounds:

```
(?<=')(\\'|[^'])+(?=')
```

This matches either `\'` *or* non quotes (attempted in that order).